# T-SQL - Using Column Name in where condition without any references when having multiple tables that are engaged using multiple joins

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am a newbie for T-Sql, I came across a SP where multiple tables are engaged using multiple joins but the where clause contain  a column field without any table reference  and assigned  for an incoming variable,like

```
where 'UserId = @UserId'
```

instead -  no table reference like

```
'a.UserId = @Userid'`
```

Can any please do refer to me any material that clears my mind regarding such issue.

Comment: You only need the explicit table reference if that column name would become ambiguous using multiple table, so if `UserId` in this example is the only column using that name across all tables used in a query, no table reference or alias is needed.

Comment: But to add to that I must say it is a good practice to always use those explicit table references (just in case), so keep up the good spirit! But please try not to fall for the habit of just shortening all table references to single letter aliases, that is not pretty and does not help reading the queries ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the query works it means that there is only one Column with the name UserId, if there are multiple columns with the same name you have to reference the table too.

If you don't specify the table reference you will get

`Ambiguous column name 'UserId'.` error

Which means there are more then 2 tables with a column name UserId.

Anyway, always try and use the reference table.